# What do we call these gates? A kind of vertical sectioned sliding gate/door

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, translation

The document I'm translating, a warehouse specification, stipulates that the warehouse's acceptance-and-shipping room should have this kind of gate (door?)

> [image]

In Russian, it's called "**подъемно-секционные ворота**". I googled this phrase and found the image attached above.

The Multitran dictionary [offers](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EF%EE%E4%FA%E5%EC%ED%EE%20%F1%E5%EA%F6%E8%EE%ED%ED%FB%E5%20%E2%EE%F0%EE%F2%E0) "vertical lift folding gate" as a translation, but I'm unsure. How are such gates (or is it "doors"?) called in English?

Comment: See Wikipedia's page for garage doors, particularly the sections for [sectional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garage_door#Sectional_garage_doors) and [roller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garage_door#Roller_doors) doors.

Comment: @Davo - thank you! It's clearly **overhead sectional door**.

Comment: Most folks in the US would call it a *garage door*.

Comment: @HotLicks same in U.K. regarding *garage door*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Roller shutter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roller_shutter):***

> A *roller shutter, roller door or sectional overhead door* is a type of door or window shutter consisting of many horizontal slats (or sometimes bars or web systems) hinged together.
>
> Roller shutters have many applications, including doors for vans, garages, etc.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Thank you! "Overhead sectional door" clearly fits the bill, as Google Image shows.